# Using Laptop Camera In Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I run my app in the Android emulator which uses Laptop camera (by changing both front and back cameras settings from "Emulated" to "Webcam0"), I got an error which is "app keeps stopping..."

***Can you kindly tell me how to fix this problem?***

Note: The O.S. that I use is Windows 10

*The Code is Attached*

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



        if(!hasCamera()) {
            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    private boolean hasCamera() {
        return  getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    public void capture(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat about the error.